# react native with sockets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sockets

Have you ever worked with sockets in React Native?
Right now, I'm using this library:

- `import io from 'socket.io-client'`

I tried to connect with this code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      socket = io(`myURL?acess_token=${user?.token}`)
      socket.on(chatId, msg => {
        console.log('sockets!!')
        console.log({ msg })
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error: ', error)
    }
  }, [])
```

But I expected ti receive a sockets!! when the connect was successful, I don't return me nothing.

Any idea what happens.

Also I tested in this page https://www.websocket.org/echo.html the sockets and is working, but not in my app.

Comment: What error are you getting? And also try putting you socket on a ref instead of a variable?

Comment: @PrateekThapa, the problem is I don't get any error when I run this code.